# return value in subscribe in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new in angular and I have searched for this for so long

I have a login method

```
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    //return this.http.post<ServiceResponse>(API_USERS_URL, { email, password });
    debugger;
    
    this.http.post<ServiceResponse>(API_USERS_URL, { email, password }).subscribe((response: ServiceResponse) => {
        
      if (response.success) {
        const auth = new AuthModel();
        auth.accessToken = "access-token-8f3ae836da744329a6f93bf20594b5cc";
        auth.refreshToken = "access-token-f8c137a2c98743f48b643e71161d90aa";
        auth.expiresIn = new Date(Date.now() + 100 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        return auth;
      }
    }, (error: ServiceResponse) => {
      console.log(error);
      return undefined;
    });
  }
```

I use subscribe to check if the response is success or not and if it is success I return value and if it is not I return undefined and log the error

there is a compilation error here that I should return value, when I add return in the end of the method, it return before the response comes from server

can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need an observable but you can return an observable using the RxJs operator `of` (the lib is already in your project)

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
    //...
return of(auth)
```

Or with a behavior subject

```
new BehaviorSubject<any>(auth)
```

**But I think the good approach for this case will be to return a `Promise`**

```
return new Promise<any>((resolve , reject) =>{
      if(login==true){ resolve(auth) }
      if(login==false){ reject() }
})
```

Your HTTP request will only "emit" once, that why there is no need for an observable. With a WebSocket observable may be more interesting

[image]

From [Promises vs Observable](https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/angular-promises-versus-observables.aspx#:%7E:text=Both%20observables%20and%20promises%20help,over%20a%20period%20of%20time.&text=Emit%20multiple%20values%20over%20a%20period%20of%20time.)

Comment: While this is true, Observables are _the idiomatic_ way in Angular of performing single-response REST calls. There's no need to promisify the result - if correctly constructed, it will emit once and then _complete_.

Comment: @msanford thank you. why should we use an observable when the HTTP response will only respond once?

Comment: As I mentioned, because it _the idiomatic way_ Angular handles REST requests, which (almost all) respond only once. How would you create any _other_ service? When seen that way, we notice that the _structure_ of the original code is wrong, which is also why this solution _even if promisified_ won't work. Hint: The return type annotation OP added `: Observable<any>` is a lie as `login()` does not return anything.

Comment: I'm reading about it, you are right - they say "to keep consistency"  observable can be used with pipes and other angular thinks... apparently promises are converted in observables under the hood

Comment: This issue of "how do I get a value out from inside a Subscribe" is a _canonical_ issue in Rxjs and there's lots written about it. That's not all, however. Only [arrow functions have implicit return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body) in JavaScript. `this.http.post...` is _invoked_ but it is not _returned_ from `login()`. For that, you need `return this.http.post...` so that the caller of login() can see it. That's why you _don't generally_ subscribe() here, but rather subscribe to login() in the caller method.

Answer (score 0):

After having a second look at the full code sample, I see that you want to return an Observable. You are not returning that at the moment.

you can create an Observable, and call .next on the observer though

```
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    this.http.post <ServiceResponse >(API_USERS_URL, { email, password }).subscribe((response: ServiceResponse) => {
          if (response.success) {
            const auth = new AuthModel();
            auth.accessToken = 'access-token-8f3ae836da744329a6f93bf20594b5cc';
            auth.refreshToken = 'access-token-f8c137a2c98743f48b643e71161d90aa';
            auth.expiresIn = new Date(Date.now() + 100 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            observer.next(auth);
          }
          observer.next(null);
        },
        (error: ServiceResponse) => {
          console.log(error);
          observer.next(null);
        }
      );
  });
}
```

Also, instead of subscribing to `http.post`, you can
`return http.post().pipe(map());`, and let the consumer of `login` do `login().subscribe()`;

```
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post <ServiceResponse >(API_USERS_URL, { email, password }).pipe(map(response => {
      if (response.success) {
        const auth = new AuthModel();
        auth.accessToken = "access-token-8f3ae836da744329a6f93bf20594b5cc";
        auth.refreshToken = "access-token-f8c137a2c98743f48b643e71161d90aa";
        auth.expiresIn = new Date(Date.now() + 100 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        return auth;
      }
      return null;
    }),
    catchError(err => {
      console.log(err);
      return undefined;
    }));    
}
```

[Here is a minimal StackBlitz example of the second approach](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mesx1g?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: OP is actually not returning an Observable (or anything). Only [arrow functions have implicit return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body) in JavaScript.